# Django 2. Проблема с обновлением страницы после написания комментария

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Занимаюсь изучением Django 2 по книге А.Меле "Django 2 в примерах".
Написал код для комментариев под постами в блоге, однако после написания комментария, форма для написания нового комментария не открывается, а при обновлении страницы повторяется тот же комментарий. Сам код:

models.py:

```py
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    email = models.EmailField()
    body = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created',)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Comment by {} on {}'.format(self.name, self.post)
```

views.py:

```py
def post_detail(request, year, month, day, post):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=post,
                                    status='published',
                                    publish__year=year,
                                    publish__month=month,
                                    publish__day=day)

    comments = post.comments.filter(active=True)
    new_comment = None

    if request.method == 'POST':
        comment_form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)
        if comment_form.is_valid():
            new_comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
            new_comment.post = post
            new_comment.save()
    else:
        comment_form = CommentForm()


    return render(request, 'blog/post/detail.html', {'post': post,
                                                      'comments': comments,
                                                      'new_comment': new_comment,
                                                      'comment_form': comment_form})
```

forms.py

```py
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('name', 'email', 'body')
```

detail.html

```py
    </p>
    {% with comments.count as total_comments %}
        <h2>
            {{ total_comments }} comment {{ total_comments|pluralize }}
        </h2>
    {% endwith %}
    {% for comment in comments %}
        <div class = "comment">
            <p class = "info">
                Comment {{ forloop.counter }} by {{ comment.name }}
                {{ comment.created }}
            </p>
            {{ comment.body|linebreaks }}
        </div>
    {% empty %}
        <p>There are no comments yet.</p>
    {% endfor %}
    {% if new_comment %}
        <h2>Your comment has been added.</h2>
    {% else %}
        <h2>Add a new comment</h2>
        <form action="." method="post">
            {{ comment_form.as_p }}
            {% csrf_token %}
            <p><input type="submit" value="Add comment"></p>
        </form>
    {% endif %}
```

На GitHub нашел код. Сверил, вроде ошибок нет. Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем проблема. Не могу найти ошибку уже несколько дней. Так же прошу прощения если что то не так с оформлением вопроса. В первый раз пишу на этот форум.

Comment: Судя по логике `views.py` и разметке шаблона `detail.html` так и должно быть. После создания комментария, переменная `new_comment` становится не пустой, поэтому блок `else` не выполняется и форма не показывается. А при обновлении страницы, созданный комментарий выводится в цикле `for comment in comments`.

Comment: @Jazzis скажите, а что можно сделать, чтобы после обновления страницы комментарий не повторялся и была форма для написания нового комментария?

Comment: Где у вас повторяется комментарий?

Comment: @Jazzis на странице блога, где расположена статья. Принтскрины:
https://d.radikal.ru/d15/2001/4e/ca250d158fe6.jpg
заполняю форму
https://a.radikal.ru/a25/2001/7c/d2ab478df2ff.jpg
комментарий добавлен, однако формы для нового комментария нет.

https://a.radikal.ru/a03/2001/71/5221cd2fdfcf.jpg
состояние страницы после обновления - комментарий повторяется.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы форма появлялась после добавления комментария, уберите блок `else` из шаблона:

```
{% if new_comment %}
    <h2>Your comment has been added.</h2>
{% endif %}
    <h2>Add a new comment</h2>
    <form action="." method="post">
        {{ comment_form.as_p }}
        {% csrf_token %}
        <p><input type="submit" value="Add comment"></p>
    </form>
```

Насчет первой части вопроса, при обновлении страницы введенные данные формы отправляются вновь (Google Chrome, например, запрашивает подтверждение об отправке).

Comment: из шаблона блок else удалил. во вьюшке после валидации формы сделал редирект 
'if comment_form.is_valid():
 new_comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
 new_comment.post = post
 new_comment.save()
 return redirect(post)'
Все заработало. Однако в адекватности такого решения не уверен.